# Access form inside ng-template in a template driven form

Tags: angular, angular-forms

```
<form #f="ngForm">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template"></ng-container>
  {{f.controls.formInput.value}} // gives error
  <ng-template #template>
    <div class="reusable-control">
      <input ngModel name="formInput">
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</form>
```

As you can see, I'm accessing `formInput` after the `ng-container` but getting an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Problem can be with that then your model is invisible in scope of ngForm so that's why you get error
https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables#how-angular-assigns-values-to-template-variables

Comment: Understood regarding the template variable. But how do I associate the form control `formInput` to the outer form @kalit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default it has nothing to display, it's empty. You have not bound the the input to anything. The form and value currently as it is, exists only in template. If you add `[(ngModel)]="input"` and `input = 'test'` to TS it would have something.

```html
Template: 
<form #f="ngForm">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template"></ng-container>

  <ng-container *ngIf="f.controls.formInput?.value">
    {{f.controls.formInput.value}}
  </ng-container>

  <ng-template #template>
    <div class="reusable-control">
      <input [(ngModel)]="input" name="formInput">
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</form>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  input = 'test';

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-q9usk3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I don't want to use Reactive Form here, my friend. Template driven form is suitable for my bigger use case.

Comment: Sorry, I completely ignored that part. Anyway, I refactored it to template driven form. The problem happens that your trying to access `value` on the control before `#template` is rendered that actually holds the input where the value should be. So somehow you have to wait till it's rendered to access it, otherwise you end up with undefined. Using `*ngIf` could be one way. Others have posted similar ideas using `?` to check if the prop is there.

Comment: No error, but it doesn't display either. I want the value to be displayed.

Comment: If you write something in there, then it will be displayed. By default it has nothing to display, it's empty. You have not bound the the input to anything. The form and value currently as it is, exists only in template. If you add `[(ngModel)]="input"` and `input = 'test'` to TS it would have something.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular v13 it's working for me

```html
<form #f="ngForm">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template"></ng-container>
  {{ f?.controls?.['formInput']?.value }}
  <ng-template #template>
    <div class="reusable-control">
      <input #formInput="ngModel" ngModel name="formInput">
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</form>
```